# Quran 21:32 protected roof or protective roof

Tags: quran, arabic-translation

وَجَعَلْنَا السَّمَاءَ سَقْفًا مَّحْفُوظًا وَهُمْ عَنْ آيَاتِهَا مُعْرِضُون

Quran 21:32

Does the word (محفوظاً) mean protected or protective

In other words what does the verse say, does it say that the canopy is the objected which is protected or does it say that the canopy protects the earth.

Answer (score 2):

No the verse says that Allah protects the sky or heaven.

> محفوظاً

clearly means protected and this is shown in several verses of the qur'an:

- > .... His Kursi extends over the heavens and the earth, **and their preservation tires Him not**. ... ([2:255](https://legacy.quran.com/2/255))
- > ... And He restrains the sky from falling upon the earth, **unless by His permissio**n. Indeed Allah , to the people, is Kind and Merciful. ([22:65](https://legacy.quran.com/22/65))
- > And of His signs is that the heaven and earth **remain by His command**. ... ([30:25](https://legacy.quran.com/30/25))
- > Indeed, **Allah holds** the heavens and the earth, lest they cease. ([35:41](https://legacy.quran.com/35/41))

and many more